# How to create outward spiral motion in Adobe After Effects?

Tags: after-effects, adobe, after-effects-expressions, motion-graphics

I want to create an outward spiral motion in Adobe AE. So how to do it?

I found an expression script for it [here](http://www.motion-graphics-exchange.com/after-effects/Creating-Circular-And-Spiral-Moton-Paths/4bc24b761907e) but it creates an inward spiral motion and I want outward spiral. And I am not able to reverse it.

```
shrink=time+1
radius=1000/shrink
angle=time*200
x=radius*Math.cos(degreesToRadians(angle))
y=radius*Math.sin(degreesToRadians(angle))
//z=0 // no depth
z=time*time // with depth
centre=[640,360,0]
add(centre,[x,y,z])
```

**What exactly I want to do?**

I want the images to spiral in a circular image from center to some particular points in the circle. And then they stop spiralling and stay at that point.
And after a while they shift to left with the whole circular image.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

That script uses the variable `shrink`, which paradoxically increases with time. Just make it decrease with time, e.g. by replacing the first line with these two:

```
var endTime =  123; //how long you want it to take, in seconds
shrink = endTime - time;
```

**Or** make the radius the product of the time and a constant, rather than dividing the radius by time, by replacing the first *two* lines with these:

```
shrink= time;
radius = 100 * time; //this will grow 100 pixels every second, adjust to suit
```

**Or** parent the images to a null, rotate it and scale it up. Then to counter the rotation and scale of the null on each image use this expression for rotation

```
0 - parent.transform.rotation
```

and for scale:

```
100 / parent.scale
```